# How should you handle major UI transitions when data changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My team and I are building a medium / large size AngularJS application and the controllers and views of a single page view can change dramatically depending on the data in 1 field:

```
if (order.state == state1) {
   load view a,b,c; controller j,k,l
}
if (order.state == state2) {
   load view a,d,e; controller k,y,x
}
```

In this case, how should I manage these dramatic UI changes? The closest I get is AngularUI Router, which has states and nested views, but I am not entirely sure how to structure the app and code the UI router to facilitate these UI changes. Note that these UI changes need to happen programmatically (ie. the moment app gets data that represents state1, UI needs to adjust accordingly).

Comment: Have you taken a look at named views in ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views? I assume this comes close to your request. Also, changing state programatically is done in ui-router with `$state.go(...)`, so this can be done very easily.